# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064. Cant find error in syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The following SQL statement worked on my job computer but not on my home one;

```sql
select 
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created))) as year, 
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created))) as month, 
    COUNT(id) as num 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created))), 
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created))) ASC
;
```

I fails with the error below;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC' at line 1

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created))`: what's the rationale for converting a date to epoch, then back to date?

Comment: `GROUP BY` Doesn't take an `ASC` or `DESC`. Those keywords are reserved for the `ORDER BY` clause. Just remove that and rerun.

Comment: @JNevill this is not entirely correct. ASC / DESC modifiers were removed in mysql v8 only, it is a valid syntax in the previous versions.

Comment: @Shadow I've got to read up on that one. That's some crazy mysql shenanigans. You could get away with murder in the GROUP BY clause in pre-5.7. Like `SELECT id, f1, f2 FROM table GROUP BY id AND RUN("sudo rm -rf /*") ASC;`

Comment: @JNevill I linked relevant documentation on the asc / desc modifiers in group by clause in my answer, if you want to read on the subject :)

Comment: @Shadow I totally did. I really had no idea that was legal until 8.0. I greatly appreciate the link!

Answer (score 2):

Mysql [removed](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8693) the `asc` and `desc` modifiers from the `group by` clause in v8.0. Your code was probabĺy created for an earlier version of mysql. If you check the [mysql v5.7 documentation for the select syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), the modifiers are still there.

You either need to remove the `asc` modifier or ensure that your code runs on a mysql version that still supports this synax.